# Console Application to send a mail every 2 hours

Tags: c#, console-application

I am working on an application which performs some tasks and send a mail of the report every 2 hours. I have tried this for 15 mins it is working (Even at log off). But if I am trying 30 mins only my first mail is being sent. I want it to be sent when my system is logged off also. Even after a restart I want my application to be running. Please suggest me.

```
            System.Timers.Timer aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
            aTimer.Start();
            aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
            aTimer.Interval = 1000 * 60 * 120;

            aTimer.Enabled = true;
            Console.WriteLine("Application started");
            Console.WriteLine("Press \'q\' to quit the sample.");
            Console.ReadLine();
            while (Console.Read() != 'q') ;
```

Comment: Although it is not impossible to do this with a console application, the preferred approach would be to create a **Windows service** (specifically intended to run contnuously in the background), or **schedule a job** that starts your console application (e.g. via command line) every two hours, as opposed to having the console application run for an indefinite amount of time.

Comment: Sounds like you want to run this on a server, or use a Windows Service to run the code.

Comment: What do you mean by "I want it to be sent when my system is logged off also"? you mean when the machine is turned off or when your user is logged out? Your machine cannot run scripts while its turned off...

Comment: I mean when the user is logged off

Comment: @JayGould Yes I want to run this on a server. For now I am testing it on a machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are managing this server, then it would be better to create a service or a scheduled task that runs this executable every 30 minutes. If you are running one exec with timers, then if it crashes, no further mails will be sent. This is not the case with service or scheduled task.

Comment: Will give it a try by creating a service

Comment: Created a service and it is working well for my requirements